# PHP JSON Decode

Tags: php, json

I am trying to change a PHP script so that it can recieve a JSON object and work with that given JSON object.   Everything works fine until I try to cycle trhough the converted-from-JSON-array-of-objects (aka 'stuff') with the for loop.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
$json = '{

    "foo":  "hi",
    "bar":  "bye"
    "stuff": [{"widget":"dd"},{"thing":"cc"},{"wcha":"dd"}] 
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$foo = $arr['foo']; //works fine
$bar = $arr['bar']; //works fine

//old way that worked:
//$stuff    = array("widget" => "dd", "thing" => "cc", "wcha" => "dd");
//new way that does not work:
$stuff = $arr['stuff'];
...

//This is where the problem is:
foreach ($stuff as $key => $value){...
```

*The problem in the for loop* is that $key is an integer (not the actual value) and $value is the word 'Array' (not the actual value).

Comment: Look at your structure and look at how you're trying to access it.  $stuff is an array of objects (or an array of arrays is what I believe it will be converted to in PHP).

Comment: your json decode gives NULL to me (nothing works fine): http://codepad.org/meAoAn0a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing exactly what it should. The problem is that you're not quite understanding it right.

"stuff" is an array of objects. So when you decode it, the resulting PHP array is this:

```
[stuff]=>
array(3)
  {
  [0]=>
  array(1)
    {
    [widget]=>string(2) "dd"
    }
  [1]=>
  array(1)
    {
    [thing]=>string(2) "cc"
    }
  [2]=>
  array(1)
    {
    [wcha]=>string(2) "dd"
    }
  }
```

So when you call `foreach` on it, you're getting the individual arrays from there.

I think your JSON should be:

```
"stuff": {"widget":"dd","thing":"cc","wcha":"dd"}
```

Either that, or your PHP code should be:

```
foreach($stuff as $element) {
    list($key,$value) = each($element);
    // now do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

of course `$key` is an integer =). `[{"widget":"dd"},{"thing":"cc"},{"wcha":"dd"}]` this is your array so key = 0 corresponds to the object `{"widget":"dd"}` and so fourth.

To get to the elements, try: `$value->widget` or `$value->thing`.

Since your objects in the stuff array don't all have the same members, you may wish to rethink the way you structure your object.

Answer (score 1):

Change your JSON to

```
$json = '{
  "foo":  "hi",
  "bar":  "bye"
  "stuff": {"widget":"dd",
            "thing":"cc",
            "wcha":"dd"} 
}';
```

This way stuff contain another dictionary like structure.

In your example you are using [] who is used to encapsulate an array, not a json object, thus the integer you have are simply the indexes of the items {"widget":"dd"}, {"thing":"cc"} and {"wcha":"dd"} in your array. For your first iteration $value["widget"] should be equal to "dd".